# Writing classes to work with dummynet

Tags: java, networking

I'm attempting to use dummynet for some simple networking (just sending a file in packets between a sender and receiver). Now, from what I can see, this is relatively simple. The problem is that I have to write the sender and receiver classes as .java files and I'm not sure how to do this, nor can I find any documentation online about this (maybe it's just really easy and I'm being an idiot).

Anyway, does anyone have links to any good tutorials or examples of this kind of thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a TCP/IP client/server application sample you're trying to write, there might be some sample code at this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/

Comment: Ah, right. So there's no special code for using dummynet. Well, that was a dumb question. Thanks for the answer though. ¬_¬

Comment: I used dummynet before as a BSD VM to simulate networks with high latency, i.e. measuring how ODBC traffic degrades over high ping.  http://codefromthe70s.org/dummynet.aspx